# The lonely product

Tags: python

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Given three numbers, a, b, and c, return their product, but if one of the numbers is the same as another, it does not count. If two numbers are similar, return the lonely number. If all numbers are same, return 1.

I have the following solution:

```
def solve(a, b, c):
    product = 0

    if a == b == c:
        product = 1
    elif a == b:
        product = c
    elif a == c:
        product = b
    elif b == c:
        product = a
    else:
        product = a * b * c
    return product
```

How can I do this better? Preferably without using any imports.

Comment: Welcome to CoreReview@SE. When/as you don't tell what to consider *better*, be prepared for personal preferences. The problem statement is funny in using *similar* - close to an integral multiple of 42?

Comment: For what it's worth, your solution is simple and obviously correct. I'd prefer it over many of the shorter less-obviously correct solutions below. As a bonus, your solution is easily transcribed into almost any language!

Comment: *grumble grumble* The **true** correct way is using binary operations...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Document your code. [In the code.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring)

Code the way **you** think about the problem - which may very well be as presented in the question.
Leave a code comment where you have unresolved concerns (like
*there should be a better way to code this, because a == b features in two conditions of a single elif chain*).

```
def solitary_numbers_product(a, b, c):
    """ return the product of the numbers specified,
        ignoring numbers occurring more than once.
    """
    if a == b:
        return 1 if b == c else c
    if a == c:
        return b
    if b == c:
        return a

    return a * b * c


solve = solitary_numbers_product
# finger exercise in functional coding
# PEP 8 puts imports at module top
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce


def unique_numbers_product(*numbers):
    """ return the product of the numbers specified,
        ignoring numbers occurring more than once.
    """
    counts = Counter(numbers)
    return reduce(lambda product, factor: product * factor,
                  filter(lambda n: counts[n] == 1, counts), 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # ToDo: develop a decent test
    numbers = tuple(ord(c) - ord('0') for c in '2353332')
    for offset in range(5):
        triple = numbers[offset:offset + 3]
        print(solve(*triple))
        print(unique_numbers_product(*triple))
```

Comment: (Darn. `b == c` occurs more than once…)

Comment: don't be too afraid of repeating code, if it makes the code more readable. I think your `solve` would be more readable if the first condition was `a == b and b ==c` and removing the ternary operator and adding an extra `if` statement. It would be more symmetrical.

Comment: The "conditional expression" is how I currently think about it (if I didn't immediately generalise to *multiple numbers*) - if it wasn't, I'd have left a comment more likely than not. I'm not overly concerned about *static* repetition when I don't see a way to (readably) avoid it - one problem with `a == b` in the question is that without recognition of common sub-expressions/conditions, it might be evaluated twice *at runtime*.

Comment: While there is a built-in function [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), but no `product()`, the lambda used is obsolete: [operator.mul](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul) is part of the Python library, and, as of 3.8, [math.prod()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.prod).

Comment: why not `tuple(int(c) for c in '2353332')` instead of `tuple(ord(c) - ord('0') for c in '2353332')`

Comment: @MaartenFabré: The sole reason is that that is the way I happen to think about it, "coming from C": I think the elements of a string to be characters, and the conversion to `int` to apply to strings. Never mind [*Python doesn’t have a char type; instead, every code point in the string is represented as a string object with length* `1`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy).

Comment: I would prefer OPs solution if I came across both in a codebase. This seems overengineered and therefore harder to understand.

Comment: @TheFool ([prepared for personal preferences](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/236520/the-lonely-product/236529?noredirect=1#comment463590_236520)) (`This seems overengineered` `solitary_numbers_product()`? `unique_numbers_product()` is commented to be a *finger exercise*.)

Answer (score 29):

For what it's worth, I think your solution is clearer than any of the alternatives posted so far. They are shorter in some cases, but I note that you asked for a *better* solution, not a shorter one. In this case, I don't believe that brevity is an improvement.

I am not a python programmer, but I can *understand* your solution. It does what it is supposed to do and it is clear what is happening in each step, and what the result will therefore be. A brief comment at the start of the method explaining what it does might be nice, and perhaps a more descriptive name for the method (although not sure what that would be in this case, since the operation seems rather arbitrary). Other than that, unless other constraints are placed on this method, such as performance, I would not change it.

The only alternative I can see that would be equally readable would be to elide the product variable entirely and simply use return statements, i.e.

```
if a == b == c:
    return 1
elif a == b:
    return c
elif a == c:
    return b
elif b == c:
    return a

return a * b * c
```

However, I do not think this is *better*, simply different, and as clear. Note that this solution [has more than one exit point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838828/why-should-a-function-have-only-one-exit-point), but it is largely a matter of opinion whether that is a bad thing or not, so I will leave that for you to decide.

Comment: Absolutely. The conditional branches in the OP's code match precisely with the wording of the problem, so it's clear that it does the right thing.

Answer (score 19):

For greater brevity, you could also solve this puzzle using Python's functional programming tools:

```
import operator
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce


def solitary_product(*numbers):
    """
    Return the product of the given numbers, ignoring all numbers
    that repeated anywhere.
    """
    counts = Counter(numbers)
    distinct_numbers = [n for n in numbers if counts[n] == 1]

    return reduce(operator.mul, distinct_numbers, 1)
```

This has the added benefit of extending your solution to collections of numbers of arbitrary length instead of just sequence of three numbers.

It is worth noting that this method would likely be less efficient for short sequences of numbers due to the added overhead of additional functions calls and constructing a new collection. However, for longer sequences, this method offers the most ideal performance, and will be much more readable than long if-else chains.

---

**Update for Python 3.8:**

The [`math`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html) module now includes the [`prod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.prod) function, which can compute the product of the elements in any iterable. Using this new feature, we can implement  this solution more briefly as

```
import math
from collections import Counter


def solitary_product(*numbers):
    """
    Return the product of the given numbers, ignoring all numbers
    that repeated anywhere.
    """
    counts = Counter(numbers)
    distinct_numbers = [n for n in numbers if counts[n] == 1]

    return math.prod(distinct_numbers)
```

Thanks to L.F. for bring this to my attention.

As mentioned in the comments, you could even express this as a one-liner at the expense of readability:

```
def solitary_product(*numbers):
    return math.prod(n for n, counts in Counter(numbers).items() if counts == 1)
```

Comment: `operator.mul` is just what I didn't manage to find. The catch is numbers occurring more than once are not to get into the product at all.

Comment: @greybeard You're absolutely right, thanks for catching that. I've updated may answer to exhibit the correct behavior for those cases.

Comment: **This is by far the best answer.** All the others are ad hoc code that handles exactly three numbers; if next week, the program needs to handle a fourth number, the given algorithms would have to be completely rewritten, and would be very complicated.  Handling the general case, as this answer does, is always the right way to do it.

Comment: You can use `math.prod` instead of reduce + operator.mul.

Comment: @L.F. Thank you for bring that function to my attention! I didn't notice it being slipped into Python 3.8.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if len(distinct_numbers) == 0:
        return 1` and I would do `distict_numbers = {number for number, count in Counter(numbers).items() if count ==1}`

Comment: Ray Butterworth I disagree, premature generalisation can be just as bad as premature optimization, and should not be encouraged at the expense of clarity and simplicity.

Comment: That test `len(distinct_numbers) == 1` seems pointless and wrong.  If we pass `(2, 2, 3)`, then `distinct_numbers` is `{3}` and we want to return `3`, not `1`.  I think the test should be `if not distinct_numbers:` instead.  Or, just unconditionally insert `1` to the set before invoking `reduce` or `math.prod`.  Actually, with `math.prod()`, we can pass an empty iterable, so it's not necessary in that version.  Then the function becomes a one-liner: `return math.prod({n for n,c in Counter(numbers).items() if count == 1})`

Comment: The `reduce` version looks similar, but we'd want `reduce(operator.mul, {1}|distinct_numbers)` to inject a `1` into the set

Comment: @MaartenFabré et al., thank you for your feedback, I agree with all of it. I had meant to remove the length comparison altogether after I edited my recommendation to make use of the `Counter` collection. I'm rather surprised that my response has had just positive response despite such a glaring error.

Comment: @doris, the general case is often simpler and clearer. Code like `if a == b: return 1 if b == c else c` doesn't make what is happening obvious.  With code like that it's not obvious that the algorithm properly handles all cases.  And think what it would look like if it had to handle 4 numbers. Code that obviously reflects the algorithm, "*remove duplicates, append 1 to the list, return the product*", is much easier for anyone to understand, debug, or modify, and gives much more confidence that it actually does what it claims to do. In 90+% of code, efficiency doesn't matter, so add that later.

Comment: `start=1` is the default value of `start`, so it's superfluous, and doesn't improve readability since `math.prod` already implies multiplying the numbers together; the product of no numbers is 1 for the same reason that the sum of no numbers is 0. The one-liner can be simplified to `math.prod(n for n, counts in Counter(numbers).items() if counts == 1)`.

Comment: @RayButterworth The general case is rarely simpler or clearer. Special cases allow you to ignore complexity - that's why we use them. Just look at the special and general theories of relativity.

Answer (score 9):

There is no need for the initial `product == 0`

And you can simplify the `elif` tree with early returns

```
def solve2(a, b, c):
    if a == b == c:
        return 1
    if a == b:
        return c
    if a == c:
        return b
    if b == c:
        return a
    return a * b * c
```

This makes the intent and logic very clear.

You can use the fact that in python, `True` and `False` are used as 1 and 0 in calculations:

```
def my_product(a, b, c):
    return (
        a ** (a not in {b, c})
        * b ** (b not in {a, c})
        * c ** (c not in {a, b})
    )
```

or

```
def my_product2(a, b, c):
    return (
        a ** (a != b and a != c)
        * b ** (b != a and b != c)
        * c ** (a != c and b != c)
    )
```

or using the new python 3.8 [`math.prod`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html#math.prod)

```
import math


def my_product_math(a, b, c):
    return math.prod(
        (
            a if a not in {b, c} else 1,
            b if b not in {a, c} else 1,
            c if c not in {a, b} else 1,
        )
    )
```

Then you need a few test cases:

```
test_cases = {
    (2, 3, 5): 30,
    (3, 5, 3): 5,
    (5, 3, 3): 5,
    (3, 3, 3): 1,
    (3, 3, 2): 2,
}
```

and you evaluate them like this:

```
[my_product(a,b,c) == result for (a,b,c), result in test_cases.items()]
```

You can even time this:

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit(
    "[func(a,b,c) == result for (a,b,c), result in test_cases.items()]",
    globals={"func": my_product, "test_cases": test_cases},
)
```

and the all together behind a main guard:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_cases = {
        (2, 3, 5): 30,
        (3, 5, 3): 5,
        (5, 3, 3): 5,
        (3, 3, 3): 1,
        (3, 3, 2): 2,
    }

    methods = [
        solve,
        solve2,
        my_product,
        my_product_math,
        solitary_product,
        solitary_numbers_product,
        solve_graipher,
        solve_kuiken,
        solve_kuiken_without_lambda,
        my_product2,
    ]

    for method in methods:
        result = all(
            [
                method(a, b, c) == result
                for (a, b, c), result in test_cases.items()
            ]
        )
        time = timeit.timeit(
            "[func(a,b,c) == result for (a,b,c), result in test_cases.items()]",
            globals={"func": method, "test_cases": test_cases},
        )
        print(f"{method.__name__}: {result} - {time}")
```

Which shows that in terms of speed, your method is one of the fastest

> ```
> solve: True - 2.324101332999817
> solve2: True - 2.386756923000121
> my_product: True - 6.072235077000187
> my_product_math: True - 5.299641845999986
> solitary_product: True - 19.69770133299994
> solitary_numbers_product: True - 2.4141538469998522
> solve_graipher: True - 4.152514871999756
> solve_kuiken: True - 7.715469948999726
> solve_kuiken_without_lambda: True - 5.158195282000179
> my_product2: True - 5.210837743999946
> ```

So I would go with the simplification of your original algorithm

Comment: I think using `elif` is better even when you are returning early, since it makes it more obvious that only one of these branches will execute (without the reader having to check that every block has a `return`). I would even recommend using `else` for the last case.

Comment: That's a matter of preference

Answer (score 7):

You can eliminate one branch by sorting the inputs:

```
def solve(a, b, c):
    if a == b == c:
        return 1
    a, b, c = sorted([a, b, c])
    if a == b:
        return c
    elif b == c:
        return a
    return a * b * c
```

This makes it a bit shorter. I also like the explicit structure of this code, it is very readable and immediately obvious what happens.

Having immediate returns makes the code also easier to read IMO, although some design philosophies prefer having only a single `return` per function, as you currently have.

In order to make this even clearer, you should add a [`docstring`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) describing what the function does. Unless required by the challenge, `solve` is also not a good name for this function, because it does not tell you anything about what the function actually does.

Comment: Thinking out-of-the-box! (getting an `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` if not bracketing the literal argument to `sorted()`.) You can shave off another comparison putting `return 1` after the `sorted()`: `return 1 if a == c else c if a == b else a if b == c else a * b * c;`. (Ever managed to un-see something?)

Comment: @greybeard: Fixed. However, I'm not a great fan of ternary expressions, unless it is in the most trivial cases, which this most certainly is not. But sure, that would also work :)

Comment: @Graipher: I'm not sure about the `sorted `, my brain has to work harder (and maybe the Python interpreter also)

Answer (score 2):

Yet another solution, using a dictionary for pattern matching. I do not know how it performs in comparison with previous solutions, but dictionaries in Python are known to be pretty efficient. Note: the keys with two `True`'s are skipped because they cannot occur.

```
SOLVE_TABLE = { ( False , False , False ) : lambda a,b,c: a * b * c,
                ( False , False , True  ) : lambda a,b,c: b,
                ( False , True  , False ) : lambda a,b,c: a,
                ( True  , False , False ) : lambda a,b,c: c,
                ( True  , True  , True  ) : lambda a,b,c: 1  }

def solve(a,b,c):
    return  SOLVE_TABLE[(a==b, b==c, c==a)](a,b,c)
```

Comment: Nice substitute for the switch statement I might have used in a language providing one, and an alternative to encoding the comparison results and using that as an index. (Nice in only evaluating the product when selected (unless I'm mistaken).)

Comment: I see no use to the `lambda` if you call it immediately. The advantage of only evaluating it when selected is lost by having to construct 6 anonymous functions

Comment: @MaartenFabré my idea with the lambda's was to make the dictionary constant, and it would be evaluated only once. I don't think it does, when I define the dict outside the function, as a 'constant', I see a speed increase.

Comment: Then I can see the point. To make this more clear, you can move this dictionary definition outside the function body.

Comment: -1. I dislike this so much.. it’s horrible... I would damn the guy who writes this at work. somewhat funny because “thinking outside of the box” but other than that more of a perfect example of how _not_ to write code IMO. I don’t want to see ‘funny code’ at work. Not to the point (what is the meaning of the last false in the fourth row again?), not readable, error prone (switch one of those booleans), implicit stuff (skipping two trues because blablabla) and last but not least: it scales horribly (4 numbers? 5? 6? Have fun with that table and skipping all the cases that can’t occur)..

Answer (score 2):

Other solutions seem really clumsy and very hard to read, here is a nice simple way to do this:

```
from collections import Counter

def solve(a, b, c):
    unique = {a, b, c}
    if len(unique) == 1:
        return 1
    if len(unique) == 3:
        return a * b * c
    return Counter((a, b, c)).most_common()[-1][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using dictionaries and mapping (and no additional imports):

```py
def solve(a, b, c):
  l = [a, b, c]
  c = lambda x: l.count(x) > 1
  z = [c(v) for v in l] # Replacing the import of Counter

  {
      (True, True): 1, 
      (False, False): l[0]*l[1]*l[2]
  }.get(map(lambda b: b(z), [all, any]), l[z.index(False)])
```

So, if `all` elements are equal, the resulting map will be `True` for `all` and `True` for `any`, if none are equal, it will be `False` for both. If the `get()` fails, return the one that has the `False` index in `z` list (the list that states, for every element, if there is more than one element of that).

Comment: There is no need for the lambda `c`. 1 letter variable names are very unclear and this method is rather convoluted. `numbers= (a,b,c); lonely= [(numbers.count(number) <1)for number in numbers]; return {
      (True, True):  a*b*c,
      (False, False):1
  }.get((any(lonely), all(lonely)), numbers[lonely.index(True)])` is more clear, but still very convoluted